# Designing contact/company/address tables for a database

Tags: sql

Trying to design part of a database to hold addresses, companies and contacts. I had one design of it in which I've now got the job of 'cleaning' it due to poor design.

Bought a copy of Joe Celko's SQL Programmer Style for reference as I'm coming from a programming angle so I ended up with...

```
Addresses
street_1_adr varchar(80) primary key
street_2_adr varchar(80)
street_3_adr varchar(80)
zip_code varchar(10) foreign key/primary key > Regions.zip_code
```

With a check to ensure all addresses are unique to prevent duplicates.

```
Regions
city varchar(80)
region varchar(80)
zip_code varchar(10) primary key
country_nbr integer foreign key/primary key > Countries.country_nbr
```

With a check to ensure all regions are unique to prevent duplicates.

```
Countries
country_nbr integer primary key
country_nm varchar(80)
country_code char(3)
```

With a check to ensure that only one record exists for all the information.

```
Companies
company_nm varchar(80) primary key
street_1_adr varchar(80) foreign key > Addresses.street_1_adr
zip_code varchar(10) foreign key > Addresses.zip_code
Extra information
```

With a check to ensure that only one company with that name can exist at the address specified

```
Contacts
company_nm varchar(80) primary key/foreign key > Companies.company_nm
first_nm varchar(80) primary key
last_nm varchar(80) primary key
Extra information
```

But this means that if I want to hook, as an example, an order onto a contact I need to do it with three fields.

Does this look right or have I completetly missed the point?

Comment: Don't abbreviate table/column names (`_nm`?  really?).  Don't suffix column names with their datatype, it should be obvious from the name of the column.  If you're using the ISO standard country numbers/codes, please label the columns as such - and the primary (unique) key for `Country` should probably be an autogen surrogate, not the numeric code.  Also remember that country names are language/region dependent - you may want another table there.  I personally believe that table names should be singular, not plural. Prefer surrogate keys, especially over something as mutable as `company_nm`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend using integer values for your primary keys
(if using mysql auto_increment is a handy feature, too)

When using your PK (primary key) as a FK (foreign key) in an different table, use the same datatype and don't save names.
You seem to save the company_name in "Contacts" even though you could simply save the ID of the company and get the name via a join-select.

IN your case it is OK, since the name is the primary key (varchar), but what happens when you get the same company name twice (eg Mc Donalds has more than one location)

ERP systems deploy those kind of structures mostly as or near as:

company (id and name)
site (id, name, FK company, additional information like address)

address (mostly referenced directly in site and sometime part of site)

region + country (all of them are "basic" data and referenced by ID in address table)

company table mostly only saves the ID and Name of an company.
site table (with foreign key relation to company) gives the "company" its adresses, legal information, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

First of all, a zip code can represent multiple cities/towns in the same state.  Also, one city can have multiple zip codes.

Usually you to not find an address table separate from the entity.  In other words, your company table should carry the full address.

The primary keys for the tables are usually unique identifiers or auto-increment numbers separate from the actual names.  That way, if a company or contact changes it's name, or a typo was entered and corrected, you do not need to cascade the change to other tables.

Comment: Great response. Just to add, varchar(80) PK will also give you performance head-aches. Much harder for SQL to compare and join on.

Comment: Address does _not_ belong in company, as these are separate from the company.  You should have a primary key to the address (which should be something numeric, as you list otherwise).  This is especially true if you have multiple businesses with the same postal address - you don't want to have the same entries twice.  Good points about the zip-code (which is more universally called the postal code.

Comment: @X-Zero, I agree with the multiple business locations.  What I meant, and should have said, was that an address by itself should not be a table.  Rather, the company table should have a child table (called CustomerLocations), that has a foreign key to the customer table.

Comment: Why shouldn't an address be it's own entity?  It certainly exists without anyone/anything actually being there.  Cities would have a hard time keeping track of things like empty lots otherwise.  It also means that you can do independent verification of the address itself (does it even exist, GPS coordinates, etc).  Making a cross-reference table for `contact` might be a good idea (in the case of one person acting as contact for multiple companies).  However, it's unclear if we need address information for the contact (which should be fk referenced from the contact table itself, probably).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to future proof your design by allowing for many addresses and contacts to be added to a company.  What you would do is create a many to many relationship by using a junction table [(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table%29)

```
Company
--------------
CompanyID (PK)
...

Address
--------------
AddressID (PK)
...

CompanyAddress
--------------
CompanyID (PK)
AddressID (PK)
```

The CompanyAddress table will allow you to have multiple addresses for each company.  You can also do the same for contacts, depending if the contact is associated with the company or the address.  Below is another link that talks about how to create the many to many relationship.

http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php